# How to put mysql data into popup window?

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, popup

I have a web page with images and when user clicks on any of the image, it has to derive data of that particular image from MYSQL database. What I am doing is using a simple JavaScript popup and putting the data from database. However I am just getting the first item from database on all images.

This is the code:

```
$files = glob("admin/images/paintings/*.*"); 
    echo '<div id="painting"><table border="0" style="width:590px;">';
    $colCnt=0;
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if ($colCnt%4==0)
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td width="25%" style="font-size:8.5px; font-family:arial">';
        echo($i);
      $num = $files[$i];
      echo '<a href="#openModal"><img id="indPainting" src="'.$num.'" align="absmiddle" /></a> <br> <div id="paintingName">';
      print $row['name'];

      echo '<div id="openModal" class="modalWindow">
        <div>

                <p>This is a sample modal window that can be created using CSS3 and HTML5.'.$row['name'].'</p>
                <a href="#ok" title="Ok" class="ok">Ok</a>
        </div>
    </div>';
      echo '</td>';
        $colCnt++;
      if ($colCnt==4)
        {
        echo '</tr>';
        $colCnt=0;
        }
        $i++;

    }
    mysql_close($con);
    include 'footer.php'; 
    ?>
```

$row['name'] is just giving out the first name as it is in a while loop. I am not being able to get other names for other images. How can this be done. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: please paste your full code, need to see your query , also as a suggestion try moving away from mysql way of getting results in php , try using PDO/mysqli

Comment: the rest of the code is just database connection. and im new to web programming. so just making a basic site.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY name");

Comment: where is the code for mysql query ,e.g. SELECT statement

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY name");

Comment: the problem is in the while loop. when the user clicks on individual images, the data of that image has to be shown. instead the popup is showing the data of first image

Comment: so what do we have in $files array?

Comment: $files = glob("admin/images/paintings/*.*");

Comment: the problem is the while loop. the popup is showing the first item. how to show all items according to respective image?

Comment: put  $i++; just after print $row['name']; and see if it works

Comment: this line will always be showing the first item
<p>This is a sample modal window that can be created using CSS3 and HTML5.'.$row['name'].'</p> what needs to be done is when another image is clicked, another item be shown

Comment: Can you put your page example please?

Comment: i am not being able put image unless 10 reputation. 
my problem is i have series of images displayed in the web page from directory and they have their own information in mysql database.
i, then have a popup modal box in the while loop. what needs to be done is when the user click on an image, information of that particular image has to be shown in the dialog box. what is happening is, the dialog box is being shown. however in all the dialog boxes, the first item is being shown because of the dialog box being inside a while loop

Answer (score 1):

Does one iteration in your while fetch single image data? And what I can understand according to your code is that you are displaying 4 image in a row.

Can you please format your code a bit..its looking too ugly.

I need to know which statement is calling your modal window.

```
<?php
$files = glob("admin/images/paintings/*.*"); 

echo '<div id="painting"><table border="0" style="width:590px;">';

$colCnt=0;
$i = 0;

echo '<tr>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    $num = $files[$i];

    echo '<td width="25%" style="font-size:8.5px; font-family:arial">';

    echo '<a href="#openModal"><img id="indPainting" src="'.$num.'" align="absmiddle" /></a> <br> 

    <div id="paintingName">';

    print $row['name'];

    echo '<div id="openModal" class="modalWindow"><div><p>This is a sample modal window that can be created using CSS3 and HTML5.'.$row['name'].'</p><a href="#ok" title="Ok" class="ok">Ok</a></div>

    </div></td>';

    $colCnt++;

    if ($colCnt % 4 == 0)
    {
        echo '</tr>';
        $colCnt=0;
    }
    $i++;

}
mysql_close($con);
include 'footer.php'; 
?>
```

Try this.
Also see how beautiful the code looks if its properly formatted..

Comment: echo '<a href="#openModal"><img id="indPainting" src="'.$num.'" align="absmiddle" /></a> <br> <div id="paintingName">';
this is calling the modal window

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     <?php
 $files = glob("admin/images/paintings/*.*"); 
echo '<div id="painting"><table border="0" style="width:590px;">';
$colCnt=4;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   for ($i = 0; $i < $colCnt; $i++) { 
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td width="25%" style="font-size:8.5px; font-family:arial">';
    echo($i);
  $num = $files[$i];
  echo '<a href="#openModal"><img id="indPainting" src="'.$num.'" align="absmiddle" /></a> <br> <div id="paintingName">';
  print $row['name'];

  echo '<div id="openModal" class="modalWindow">
    <div>

            <p>This is a sample modal window that can be created using CSS3 and HTML5.'.$row['name'].'</p>
            <a href="#ok" title="Ok" class="ok">Ok</a>
    </div>
</div>';
  echo '</td>';


}
     if ($colCnt==4)
    {
    echo '</tr>';
    $colCnt=0;
    }
}
mysql_close($con);
include 'footer.php'; 


 ?>
```